# undefined is not an object this.props error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to follow this ( [link](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-authentication-flow-works-in-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation-4-x-a30bb4d9e5d6) ) tutorial for navigating between sign up and login pages. Part way through it I get the error :

**undefined is not an object this.props**

I am getting this error when I try to add the following button in Login.js :

```
<Button
   title='Go to SignUp'
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
/>
```

This is before the part where the article talks about 'Managing authentication flow'. I have implemented all the code before this section but I'm not able to proceed further. Please help.

Here's a link to the expo snack. 
https://snack.expo.io/rkuPjzLRr

Comment: Can you share the exact error log ?

Comment: I cannot share the exact error log however this.props.navigation.navigate is undefined and the entire source code can be found in the link.

Comment: Is that Button define inside a class or a pure function component? If it is a pure function you can't access props in that mode

Comment: can you share your code in an expo snack so that we can check?

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong without code but it looks like a simple error

Comment: I updated the question to include the Expo snack link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's no `props` in your `Login` (that identifier isn't declared anywhere). Instead of

```
export default function Login() {
```

do

```
export default function Login(props) {
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked but I had to take the 'this' keyword out in the onPress(). Thank you so much for suggesting this!

Comment: Ah, right. `this.props` is for class components (` ...extends React.Component`), not for functional components.

Answer (score 0):

the problem says that he can't find navigation in the props, be sure that your component is in the stack navigator your component can't get the navigation prop without it

```
const AuthNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Signup: { screen: Signup }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just checked. The component is present in the stack navigator.

Comment: @sublime_archon hhmm try to console.log your props in your component to see if the navigation is there

Comment: I did that. I'm getting undefined for that too.